# build blender in visual studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, shell, cmake, blender

### building Blender

I am following the blender manual to compile, it is redundant to say that they assume that they are all expert compilers and know everything about cmake or visual studio

well ... I have this couple of lines to create a project in visual studio 2013 to 2017 according to the version that is installed on your pc.
in my case it's 2017 pro and community

### Steps

and says this
Building from within the Visual Studio IDE
If you want to work within the visual studio IDE instead of building from the command prompt.

We provide a convenience batch file in Blender's source directory which can generate a visual studio project for you.

From the command line, run:

```
cd C:\blender-git\blender
make full nobuild
```

if you want to customize your build (i.e. select a visual studio version, platform architecture, of blender feature set), you can get a list of customizable options by typing:

```
make help
```

Once the batch file finishes it should tell you where the project files have been written, for example:

```
-- Build files have been written to: c:/blender-git/build_windows_Full_x64_vc14_Release
```

### Result

`I got this build_windows_Full_x64_vc15_Release`

I continue with <kbd>make help</kbd>, and I show this list that is not used with exactness and that does not include any example to know in what order the options apply to my sample an example of syntax

```
enience targets
    - release (identical to the official blender.org builds)
    - full (same as release minus the cuda kernels)
    - lite
    - headless
    - cycles
    - bpy

Utilities (not associated with building)
    - clean (Target must be set)
    - update
    - nobuild (only generate project files)
    - showhash (Show git hashes of source tree)

Configuration options
    - verbose (enable diagnostic output during configuration)
    - with_tests (enable building unit tests)
    - noge (disable building game engine and player)
    - debug (Build an unoptimized debuggable build)
    - packagename [newname] (override default cpack package name)
    - buildir [newdir] (override default build folder)
    - x86 (override host auto-detect and build 32 bit code)
    - x64 (override host auto-detect and build 64 bit code)
    - 2017 (build with visual studio 2017)
    - 2017pre (build with visual studio 2017 pre-release)
    - 2017b (build with visual studio 2017 Build Tools)

Experimental options
    - 2015 (build with visual studio 2015)
    - clang (enable building with clang)
    - asan (enable asan when building with clang)
    - ninja (enable building with ninja instead of msbuild)
```

**How do I have to configure my command line to get a complete project nobuild and be able to choose 32 or 64 bits??**

It is necessary to clarify that if I read all the questions that the list of suggestions showed me, before formulating mine, some have given me a very superficial idea of what it is that puts me in the problem and that I am not far from solving it but none fits my problem or adapts enough to solve it by myself

[image: git folder]
[image: cmd screenshot]

Comment: Look into defining CFLAGS/CXXFLAGS. For example gcc accepts `-m32` and `-m64` to choose between 32/64 bit. You can also use `-march=<CPU>` where cpus like `i686` are 32bit only and `nocona` or newer have 64 bit support.

Comment: sounds more complicated than I thought, I've been reading the subject since I put the question, and that caused more doubts, like the following, as when I can apply commands that are not in that guide, for example what you put not even how to read it, and now I'll have to read more to understand what you mean

Comment: could you adjust to what is shown in the menu? it is assumed that only with that you must be able to obtain the desired result, only that there is not much to read that is punctual, they always jump from one subject to another without concluding one when you are already in a mess trying to read another topic that you send them to return to the same topic where you started and you did not finish solving anything because you have to look for more things that you mentioned that you do not know

Comment: CFLAGS/CXXFLAGS this gives for another question and it will be like that, where do I look for this CFLAGS / CXXFLAGS, in a blender repository?

Comment: While there are a lot of different compiler flags available, you are only interested in adding one. I don't use windows, but in *nix I can have `CFLAGS+=-m32` and that option will be used when compiling every file. For visual studio there should be project settings for compiler flags that will be applied to every file in the project.

Comment: They aren't in the blender repo, they are environment settings used by the build tools.

Comment: but I do not want to compile, compile is done with **make full x32**, what I want is to create the project within Visual Studio **nobuild**

Comment: 32/64 bit is about the compiled binary if you don't want the final binary, you don't need any 32/64 bit options. If you are configuring the project for someone else to build, then you want to configure the project settings. The name of the build directory can be anything, the script you run to create the VS project will be where the build folder name is defined.

Comment: If you look in `build_files/windows/parse_arguments.cmd` it would appear that adding `x86` to the make command will setup a 32 bit environment.

Comment: you wrong, please read my other questions hiere, and i solve the problem 10 minutes ago

Answer (score 0):

### Solved

```
c:\make full x86 nobuild
```

[image: make full x86 nobuild]